# Video streaming, with minimum delay

Tags: video

My goal is to stream a video from my pc, to a smartphone.
However, i want the latency between us to be minimal.

VIDEO -> ENCODING -> TRANSFER -> DECODING -> VIDEO

I already know that the transfer will take approximately 50ms.
What i want to know is different methods of encoding/decoding and how fast they are. The decoding smartphone will of course have limited computing power, and limited bandwidth available as well. As far as i can understand, less time encoding/decoding means more bandwidth usage. The whole operation above should take maximum 200ms, preferably less.

EDIT:
@gnat I'm just looking for some numbers on how fast a coder/decoder can work. I'm not very experienced with this kind of theory at all, seeing as i only know very basic c#. That is why i asked here, and not on stackoverflow. I've searched around quite a lot but haven't really found anything about coding/decoding speed at all, and all i wanted was some example numbers like Per was kind enough to provide.

Other then that, this was a very theoretical question, as i have used VLC media server for the purpose above. I just found it easier to ask with a simple example.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: The transfer time of 50ms is probably the greatest variable, seconded by encoding software and CPU speed.

I can decode-and-recode a 720x576 50Hz (interlaced) mpeg2 TV clip to mpeg4 640x480 30 fps at around 14ms per frame using 1 core of a Core i7 3770K 3.5 GHz CPU, using ffmpeg on a Linux box, encoding 74-80 frames per second.

I didn't write an answer, as I cannot answer your question fully, just give you my experience.